# No animation when deselecting UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, viewwillappear

I'm using [Loren Brichter's FastScrolling UITableView subclass](http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/) in my iOS app, and I have a problem properly deselecting the cells in the table view, when it's pushed back on top of the stack. My `viewWillAppear` method looks like this:

```
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:YES];
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
    }
```

The cell is deselected, but without any animation. How can I fix this?

**Update**

If I remove the code above, the exact same thing happens. Could it be that a new instance of the table view is added on top of the old every time the view is pushed on top of the stack?

Comment: You have missed out `super viewWillAppear` you should get a wait_fences.. log for that.

Comment: I've edited the post. Still doesn't work.

Comment: that would't make it work, thats why I didn't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

because your cell is probably deselected before your deselect-call and you are deselecting in the `viewWillAppear`-method. So at this moment the view is not visible.

try to use your code in `viewDidAppear`.